# How to upload single file with multiple path in codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, image-uploading

I need to upload a single image file to multiple paths. I tried many ways. but I failed. Please help me to overcome this.

My code looks like this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './img/post_images/family/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $field_name ="img_fld";
        $rgpic="0";
        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
        {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $data['error']=$error;
        }
        else
        {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $regpicname=$data['file_name'];
        $rgpic="1";
        }
        if($rgpic!=0)
        {
         $data = array(test_img'=>'img/'.$regpicname,
                         );
                  }
         $query = $this->db->insert('images',$data);
```

I need to upload same image to another directory. please help me . thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `copy()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use php copy() function to duplicate the file into another directory... Your current upload path is

```
$config['upload_path'] = './img/post_images/family/';
```

And you have stored the filename to $regpicname

So do this to get current file path

```
$original_path = $config['upload_path'].$regpicname;
 $new_path = "file path+name+extension";
```

Then use

```
copy($original_path, $new_path);
```

To duplicate... Note that if the file already exists in the new directory, it would be overwritten...